# While installing 'sudo npm install -g @angular/cli ' its gives error in ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I am facing issue When I try to install Angular-CLI on ubunutu   
My Node.js and npm version

1. Node-v9.11.1
2. npm - 5.6.0

   Command I executed 
     `savera9@savera9-desktop:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` 
   **I am Getting Below Error**

   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Cloning into bare
   >   repository
   >   '/home/savera9/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-515723dd'...
   >
   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Permission denied
   >   (publickey).
   >
   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli fatal: Could not read
   >   from  remote repository.
   >
   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli
   >
   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Please make sure you
   >   have the correct access rights
   >
   > npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli and the repository
   >   exists.
   >
   > npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli
   >
   > npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'angular/cli'
   >
   > npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
   >
   > npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
   >
   > npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
   >
   > npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-101-generic
   >
   > npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
   >   "-g" "@angular/cli"
   >
   > npm ERR! cwd /home/savera9
   >
   > npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
   >
   > npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
   >
   > npm ERR! path angular/cli
   >
   > npm ERR! code ENOENT
   >
   > npm ERR! errno 34
   >
   > npm ERR!
   >
   > npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   >
   > npm ERR!     /home/savera9/npm-debug.log
   >
   > npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: The node/npm versions you say you have don't match what the error messages says you have. Are you certain you have those newer versions installed properly?

Comment: Try after clearing cache

Comment: yes @R.Richards i installed it properly

Comment: Did you have Internet connection during the install? Maybe you are behind the proxy? For more information, please run installation with -d flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use **sudo** command it not worked but when I use **su sudo** command then it working fine.

Introduction to Linux command 'su':-

The Linux command 'su' is used to switch from one account to another. User will be prompted for the password of the user switching to.

Users can also use it to switch to root account. If user types only 'su' without any option then It will be considered as root and user will be prompted to enter root user password.

useful link :- [introduction for Su command](https://www.linux.com/blog/how-use-sudo-and-su-commands-linux-introduction)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not having proper admin rights to install the angular cli. Try using an admin account or consult with the IT team for proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall using this command -
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

and try to install again using below command  -

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I've had issues where network traffic or other hiccups prevented it from installing the first time.